# RPI4 fails to transmit nor receive data within the Keyboard&Mouse

Tags: pi-4, keyboard, mouse, bootloader, rpi-update

I am facing a critical problem with my **Raspberry Pi 4 B**(8GB) after using **rpi-update** (which installed a bugged kernel and kept on overloading the processor and the Green LED kept on lighting continuously until I shut it down...)
I tried reinstalling many distributions such as Kali and Raspberry Pi OS for more than 4 times and it always fails to boot (kernel panic even if it is a fresh install without any changes) and the keyboard&mouse are not working and sometimes it can't transmit voltage to the mouse and keyboard and they aren't even lighting (those RGB LEDs)...

after a lot of attempts
I found that Keyboard&Mouse seems like it doesn't transmit or receive any data except when the ACPI and CPU reach 40 Degrees Celsius
I don't really know how but this is a big possibility

- please note that I tried reflashing the boot loader but that didn't make any difference too...

Comment: "installed a bugged kernel" - oh, did the Raspberry Pi Foundation release a bad kernel?

Comment: edge releases are possibly to contain bugs and that is why it is called "edge" (any software stuff can get bugged)

Comment: and since then, your pi doesn't work with stable images? (I never knew Rpi released what you call "edge" releases of the kernel) if "regular" stable images, with regular stable bootloader fail, you probably broke something

Comment: **rpi-update** is known to install edge releases of kernel and boot loader and that is why everyone is complaining about booting&system problems after updating using that command... and as I said in the last few lines that it seems to work only when it reaches 40 degrees (i don't really know how but it is a big possibility)

Comment: oh, sure, yeah, rpi-update - forgot about that thing. Anyway, you say now that unmodified images don't boot - i.e. you state that `it always fails to boot (kernel panic even if it is a fresh install without any changes)` so- even if you DONT run rpi-update, your pi now *"always fails to boot"* - which makes me wonder how you know that anything works "at 40 degrees", since, it *"**always** fails to boot"*

Comment: as I said in the last few lines that I had tried a lot of times to get it working and after some tries, i found that it gets working after being warm and reaching 40 degrees

Comment: Did you ACTUALLY read the warning when you installed rpi-update. If so WHY did you ignore it?

Comment: you can call it stupid behavior :( unfortunately, i ignored that warning for no reason

Comment: Work through the raspberrypi.org/forums Pi4 boot sticky, No point us duplicating that here.

Comment: what's not clear is why a completely regular install of raspberry pi OS would "remember" that you once ran rpi-update on a previous install ... if the problem persists on an install that has not has rpi-update executed, then it has nothing to do with rpi-update - you possibly did *something else*

Comment: it seems to be a problem on the board itself (hardware related problem) but really i can't find out what is it

Comment: **you possibly did something else** I can't really remember